# Give function to several checkboxes, checked or not

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, checkbox

I am trying to do a function that prints me which of the checkbox are checked and what checkboxes are not checked after pressing a button.
The next step is: if those who are True do one operation, those that have False do another.
The final purpose is sending the values of the checkbox to txt.file. For that im gonna use the code on this site "[https://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/](https://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip//)"

This is my code:

```js
var check1 = document.getElementById('Port1');
check1.checked = false;
var check2 = document.getElementById('Port2');
check2.checked = false;
var check3 = document.getElementById('Port3');
check3.checked = false;
var check4 = document.getElementById('Port4');
check4.checked = false;
var check5 = document.getElementById('Port5');
check5.checked = false;
var check6 = document.getElementById('Port6');
check6.checked = false;
var check7 = document.getElementById('Port7');
check7.checked = false;
var check8 = document.getElementById('Port8');
check8.checked = false;
var check9 = document.getElementById('Port9');
check9.checked = false;
var check10 = document.getElementById('Port10');
check10.checked = false;
var check11 = document.getElementById('Port11');
check11.checked = false;
var check12 = document.getElementById('Port12');
check12.checked = false;
var check13 = document.getElementById('Port13');
check13.checked = false;
var check14 = document.getElementById('Port14');
check14.checked = false;
var check15 = document.getElementById('Port15');
check15.checked = false;
var check16 = document.getElementById('Port16');
check16.checked = false;
var check17 = document.getElementById('Port17');
check17.checked = false;
var check18 = document.getElementById('Port18');
check18.checked = false;
var check19 = document.getElementById('Port19');
check19.checked = false;
var check20 = document.getElementById('Port20');
check20.checked = false;
var check21 = document.getElementById('Port21');
check21.checked = false;
var check22 = document.getElementById('Port22');
check22.checked = false;
var check23 = document.getElementById('Port23');
check23.checked = false;
var check24 = document.getElementById('Port24');
check24.checked = false;

function savePortsAsFile() {
  if (check1.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port1').value);
  } else if (check1.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port1').value);
  }
  if (check2.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port2').value);
  } else if (check2.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port2').value);
  }

  if (check3.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port3').value);
  } else if (check3.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port3').value);
  }

  if (check4.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port4').value);
  } else if (check4.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port4').value);
  }

  if (check5.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port5').value);
  } else if (check5.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port5').value);
  }

  if (check6.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port6').value);
  } else if (check6.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port6').value);
  }

  if (check7.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port7').value);
  } else if (check7.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port7').value);
  }

  if (check8.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port8').value);
  } else if (check8.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port8').value);
  }

  if (check9.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port9').value);
  } else if (check9.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port9').value);
  }

  if (check10.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port10').value);
  } else if (check10.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port10').value);
  }

  if (check11.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port11').value);
  } else if (check11.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port11').value);
  }

  if (check12.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port12').value);
  } else if (check12.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port12').value);
  }

  if (check13.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port13').value);
  } else if (check13.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port13').value);
  }

  if (check14.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port14').value);
  } else if (check14.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port14').value);
  }

  if (check15.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port15').value);
  } else if (check15.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port15').value);
  }

  if (check16.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port16').value);
  } else if (check16.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port16').value);
  }

  if (check17.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port17').value);
  } else if (check17.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port17').value);
  }

  if (check18.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port18').value);
  } else if (check18.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port18').value);
  }

  if (check19.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port19').value);
  } else if (check19.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port19').value);
  }

  if (check20.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port20').value);
  } else if (check20.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port20').value);
  }

  if (check21.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port21').value);
  } else if (check21.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port21').value);
  }

  if (check22.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port22').value);
  } else if (check22.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port22').value);
  }

  if (check23.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port23').value);
  } else if (check23.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port23').value);
  }

  if (check24.checked === true) {
    document.write("true" + document.getElementById('Port24').value);
  } else if (check24.checked === false) {
    document.write("false" + document.getElementById('Port24').value);
  }
```

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port1" value="1" id="Port1">Port1</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port2" value="2" id="Port2">Port2</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port3" value="3" id="Port3">Port3</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port4" value="4" id="Port4">Port4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port5" value="5" id="Port5">Port5</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port6" value="6" id="Port6">Port6</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port7" value="7" id="Port7">Port7</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port8" value="8" id="Port8">Port8</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port9" value="9" id="Port9">Port9</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port10" value="10" id="Port10">Port10</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port11" value="11" id="Port11">Port11</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port12" value="12" id="Port12">Port12</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port13" value="13" id="Port13">Port13</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port14" value="14" id="Port14">Port14</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port15" value="15" id="Port15">Port15</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port16" value="16" id="Port16">Port16</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port17" value="17" id="Port17">Port17</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port18" value="18" id="Port18">Port18</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port19" value="19" id="Port19">Port19</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port20" value="20" id="Port20">Port20</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port21" value="21" id="Port21">Port21</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port22" value="22" id="Port22">Port22</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port23" value="23" id="Port23">Port23</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="port24" value="24" id="Port24">Port24</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<input class="buttonSave" type="button" value="Save" id="btnSave" onclick="savePortsAsFile();" />
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Ok sorry, the problem is, that i only can get the value of the first checkbox.
If its checked or not. Can you see what im doing wrong ?

The result that im getting is only "true1" if its checked, or "false1" if is not checked. And im not getting the others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that code:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");


function savePortsAsFile() {
  var checkedArray = [];
  inputs.forEach(function (i) {
    checkedArray = checkedArray.concat(
      {
        name: i.name,
        checked: i.checked
      }
    );
  });
  // console.log(checkedArray);
  var json = JSON.stringify(checkedArray);
  var blob = new Blob([json], {
    type: "application/json"
  });
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var a = document.getElementById('anchorD');
  a.download    = "inputs.json";
  a.href        = url;
  a.textContent = "Download";
}
```

[jsBin sample](http://jsbin.com/towasey/edit?html,js,output)